# Next.js can't get window size without bad hook call or undefined window?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

I've been trying to dynamically size an image in a next.js app (to make it work with different screen sizes), but the different approaches I've tried and seen have all given me either invalid hook call error or undefined window error.

```
const [width, setWidth]   = useState(typeof window === 'undefined' ? 0 : window.innerWidth);
const [height, setHeight] = useState(typeof window === 'undefined' ? 0 : window.innerHeight);
const updateDimensions = () => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    setHeight(window.innerHeight);
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateDimensions);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateDimensions);
}, []);
```

Comment: Rather than using JavaScript, have you considered resizing the images with CSS instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the outer function in the `useEffect` hook, you can try to give it as callback argument, so that it looks like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateDimensions);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateDimensions);
}, [updateDimensions]);
```

Reason for this could be that the component is server-side rendered and can't pick up the outer function as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try Hooks like that

```
const useWidth = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)
  const handleResize = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth)
  useEffect(() => {
      handleResize()
      window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
      return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])
  return width
}
```